# What is the lowest bandwidth rate limit required for a normal middle relay?

Tags: relays, network-health

Is there any technical limit for scalability by lowest bandwidth rate limit or any curve x = number of nodes, y = minimal bandwidth limit?

What settings are optimal for huge amount of small middle relays?

Answer (score 2):

Not that there's a technical bandwidth limit but it's probably not gonna be helpful for the network if you run a relay with less than 100KB/s bandwidth. For that it simply slows the network down. You can add as many relay as you want, as long as you configure the `MyFamily` correctly.

If you have less than 100KB/s bandwidth, you may consider running a [bridge relay](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq#RelayOrBridge). (there's no need to set `MyFamily` for bridges)

Comment: Also note that the Tor people measure bandwidth in Bytes and not Bits.  Networking heathens.

Comment: Yes. The capital B is not a typo. so ~100KB/s = ~800kb/s

Comment: The configuration option is named MyFamily.